# table [name] has no column named [other_name] -- restarting/upgrading DB?

Tags: php, android, mysql, sql, sqlite

I've been trying to add a column to a database. I started using [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/), but need to add another field in the table in the database called 'network'. I edited the code in a couple of places to do so. Registration works, but logging in does not.

I keep getting the error described in the title, along with a bunch of others:

[image: errors galore]

I have been looking through some of the answers on StackOverflow and have tried as many as I could. I have deleted my database and my table and created it anew. I am using WAMP, so to restart from scratch, I uninstalled and reinstalled WAMP. I also uninstalled WAMP again and switched to XAMPP, but the problem stayed. The error won't go away. What else could it be? (Just to be clear, I am now using WAMP again.)

Please let me know if you need any more code. Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Here are the php files, in WAMP's 'www' folder, in my taxi_login_api folder:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['tag']) && $_POST['tag'] != '') {
    // get tag
    $tag = $_POST['tag'];

    // include db handler
    require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
    $db = new DB_Functions();

    // response Array
    $response = array("tag" => $tag, "success" => 0, "error" => 0);

    // check for tag type
    if ($tag == 'login') {
        // Request type is check Login
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check for user
        $user = $db->getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
        if ($user != false) {
            // user found
            // echo json with success = 1
            $response["success"] = 1;
            $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
            $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
            $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
            $response["user"]["network"] = $user["network"];
            $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
            $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // user not found
            // echo json with error = 1
            $response["error"] = 1;
            $response["error_msg"] = "Incorrect email or password!";
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else if ($tag == 'register') {
        // Request type is Register new user
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $network = $_POST['network'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        // check if user is already existed
        if ($db->isUserExisted($email)) {
            // user is already existed - error response
            $response["error"] = 2;
            $response["error_msg"] = "User already existed";
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // store user
            $user = $db->storeUser($name, $email, $network, $password);
            if ($user) {
                // user stored successfully
                $response["success"] = 1;
                $response["uid"] = $user["unique_id"];
                $response["user"]["name"] = $user["name"];
                $response["user"]["email"] = $user["email"];
                $response["user"]["network"] = $user["network"];
                $response["user"]["created_at"] = $user["created_at"];
                $response["user"]["updated_at"] = $user["updated_at"];
                echo json_encode($response);
            } else {
                // user failed to store
                $response["error"] = 1;
                $response["error_msg"] = "Error occured in Registartion";
                echo json_encode($response);
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "Invalid Request";
    }
} else {
    echo "Access Denied";
}
?>
```

www/taxi_login_api/include/DB_Functions.php:

```
    <?php

    class DB_Functions {

        private $db;

        //put your code here
        // constructor
        function __construct() {
            require_once 'DB_Connect.php';
            // connecting to database
            $this->db = new DB_Connect();
            $this->db->connect();
        }

        // destructor
        function __destruct() {

        }

        /**
         * Storing new user
         * returns user details
         */
        public function storeUser($name, $email, $network, $password) {
            $uuid = uniqid('', true);
            $hash = $this->hashSSHA($password);
            $encrypted_password = $hash["encrypted"]; // encrypted password
            $salt = $hash["salt"]; // salt
            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users(unique_id, name, email, network, encrypted_password, salt, created_at) VALUES('$uuid', '$name', '$email', '$network', '$encrypted_password', '$salt', NOW())");
            // check for successful store
            if ($result) {
                // get user details 
                $uid = mysql_insert_id(); // last inserted id
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid");
                // return user details
                return mysql_fetch_array($result);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Get user by email and password
         */
        public function getUserByEmailAndPassword($email, $password) {
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
            // check for result 
            $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
                $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);
                $salt = $result['salt'];
                $encrypted_password = $result['encrypted_password'];
                $hash = $this->checkhashSSHA($salt, $password);
                // check for password equality
                if ($encrypted_password == $hash) {
                    // user authentication details are correct
                    return $result;
                }
            } else {
                // user not found
                return false;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Check user is existed or not
         */
        public function isUserExisted($email) {
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT email from users WHERE email = '$email'");
            $no_of_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
            if ($no_of_rows > 0) {
                // user existed 
                return true;
            } else {
                // user not existed
                return false;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Encrypting password
         * @param password
         * returns salt and encrypted password
         */
        public function hashSSHA($password) {

            $salt = sha1(rand());
            $salt = substr($salt, 0, 10);
            $encrypted = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);
            $hash = array("salt" => $salt, "encrypted" => $encrypted);
            return $hash;
        }

        /**
         * Decrypting password
         * @param salt, password
         * returns hash string
         */
        public function checkhashSSHA($salt, $password) {

            $hash = base64_encode(sha1($password . $salt, true) . $salt);

            return $hash;
        }

    }

    ?>
```

DB_Connect:

```
    <?php
    class DB_Connect {

        // constructor
        function __construct() {

        }

        // destructor
        function __destruct() {
            // $this->close();
        }

        // Connecting to database
        public function connect() {
            require_once 'include/config.php';
            // connecting to mysql
            $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            // selecting database
            mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);

            // return database handler
            return $con;
        }

        // Closing database connection
        public function close() {
            mysql_close();
        }

    }

    ?>
```

LoginActivity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity
{
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private ActionBar actionBar;

    // JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS = "success";
//    private static String KEY_ERROR = "error";
//    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static String KEY_NETWORK = "network";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    TextView loginErrorMsg;

    public void submitLoginFields(View view) 
    {
        Log.v("Testing", "submitLoginFields method");
        final EditText emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailEditTextLogin);
        final EditText passwordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passEditTextLogin);
        loginErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_error);

        email = emailField.getText().toString();
        password = passwordField.getText().toString();

        Log.v("Testing", "Login email: " + email);
        Log.v("Testing", "Login Password: " + password);

         new MyAsyncTask().execute(email, password);
    }

    private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>
    {   
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String ... params)
        {
            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            if (params.length != 2)
                return null;
            JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(params[0], params[1]);
            return json;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json)
        {
            try
            {
                Log.v("Testing", "b");
                if (json != null && json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null)
                {
                    Log.v("Testing", "c");
                    loginErrorMsg.setText("");
                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1)
                    {
                        Log.v("Testing", "b");
                        // user successfully logged in
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        UserDatabaseHandler db = new UserDatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        // Clear all previous data in database
                        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json_user.getString(KEY_NETWORK),
                                json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT)); //TODO                        

                        // Launch Dashboard Screen
                        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class);

                        // Close all views before launching Dashboard
                        dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(dashboard);

                        finish(); // Close login screen
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Error in login
                        loginErrorMsg.setText(R.string.error_message_login);
                    }
                }
            } 
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                loginErrorMsg.setText("Server error. Please try again later.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

UserFunctions.java:

```
public class UserFunctions {

    private JSONParser jsonParser;

    // Testing in localhost using wamp or xampp
    // use http://10.0.2.2/ to connect to your localhost ie http://localhost/
    private static String loginURL = "http://10.0.2.2/taxi_login_api/";
    private static String registerURL = "http://10.0.2.2/taxi_login_api/";

    private static String login_tag = "login";
    private static String register_tag = "register";

    // constructor
    public UserFunctions()
    {
        Log.v("Testing", "Calling UserFunctions constructor");
        jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    }

    /**
     * Method to make a login request.
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password)
    {
        // Building parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
        return json;
    }

    /**
     * Method to make a registration request.
     * @param name
     * @param email
     * @param password
     * */
    public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String network, String password) // TODO
    {
        // Building parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("network", network)); // TODO
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        // getting JSON Object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
        return json; // return json
    }

    /**
     * Method to get login status. Returns true if logged in, false if not.
     * */
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context)
    {
        UserDatabaseHandler db = new UserDatabaseHandler(context);
        int count = db.getRowCount();
        if(count > 0) // user logged in
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Method to logout user and reset database.
     * */
    public boolean logoutUser(Context context)
    {
        UserDatabaseHandler db = new UserDatabaseHandler(context);
        db.resetTables();
        return true;
    }

}
```

UserDatabaseHandler:

```
public class UserDatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "user_db";
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    private static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_NETWORK = "network"; // TODO 
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    public UserDatabaseHandler(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + KEY_NETWORK + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ");"; // TODO
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String name, String email, String network, String uid, String created_at)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_NETWORK, network); // TODO
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created at
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails()
    {
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("network", cursor.getString(3)); // TODO
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(4));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(5));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Getting user login status
     * return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount()
    {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();
        return rowCount;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null); // Delete all rows
        db.close();
    }
}
```

JSONParser.java:

```
public class JSONParser 
{ 
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params)
    {
        Log.v("Testing", "JSONParser class, getJSONFromUrl method");
        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new 
                    InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("JSON", json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);           
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
        return jObj; // return JSON String
    }
}
```

I hope I didn't paste too much; I just figured too much is better than too little. Again thank you; I have been stuck on this for two days now and am out of ideas to try. I don't know how to further restart the database, even though that seems to have solved some others' problems with regards to this error.

Comment: Hey, not sure what that means. Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Lots of code, out which only a handful is relevant to the exception (which you should include as text and not as images). Uninstall your app and reinstall it so the local database gets recreated.

Comment: Hi @laalto, okay, I'll remove as much as possible. (My bad, like I said I was trying to make it as clear as possible but I did the opposite...)

How can I uninstall my app? Every time I change emulator I 'reinstall' it. Like I said I already changed WAMP/XAMPP around in an effort to do so.

Comment: WAMP/XAMPP and the PHP has nothing to do with the local sqlite database. Uninstall using the app manager in settings, or on command line with `adb uninstall mypackage`. Or just "clear app data" in the app manager.

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you so much for explaining what was meant by uninstalling the app and for bearing with me despite my Code Manhattan.

If you submit this as an answer I can give it a green check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SQLiteOpenHelper` calls your `onCreate()` only when the database file does not exist. If you modify the table schema in the database helper, you'll have to make sure any existing database file is also updated.

During development, the easiest way is to simply force database creation by deleting the database file. This can be accomplished by uninstalling the application, or clearing application data in app manager.